# How I do the sharing information between ViewModels in project MVVM Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How I do the sharing information between ViewModels in project MVVM Toolkit? 
In MVVM Light is able to use the Messenger to the share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). Look at this post for [QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).